# Configure pod retention value of jenkins kubernetes plugin using groovy

Tags: jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-kubernetes

Trying to configure pod retention value  for Jenkins Kubernetes plugin using
groovy script.
kubernetes.setPodRetention(org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.pod.retention.Podretention.Never())
method is failing to configure with below error :

Invalid value provided in main configuration No signature of method: static
org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.pod.retention.PodRetention.Never()
is applicable for argument types: () values: []

tried configuring by using different values for the method:
kubernetes.setPodRetention(org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.pod.retention.Never)

Error using the above value as well.

Please someone help me with this as I was struck with this from quite along.

Below is the code:

```
    import java.util.logging.Logger
    import hudson.*
    import hudson.model.*
    import java.io.PrintWriter
    import java.io.StringWriter
    import jenkins.*
    import jenkins.install.InstallState
    import jenkins.model.*
    import jenkins.util.xml.*
    import javax.xml.xpath.*
    import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.*
    import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.*
    import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.common.*
    import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.domains.*
    import com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.*
    import org.jenkinsci.plugins.plaincredentials.impl.*
    import org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.credentials.*
    import org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.*
    import org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.pod.retention.PodRetention

    KubernetesCloud kubernetes = new KubernetesCloud('test')
    kubernetes.setServerUrl('http://test_url')
    kubernetes.setMaxRequestsPerHostStr(20)
    kubernetes.setPodRetention(org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.pod.retention.PodRetention.Never())
    kubernetes.setWaitForPodSec(90)
```

// documentation reference

https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/kubernetes/

// Method used 
   setPodRetention(PodRetention podRetention)
Set the global pod retention policy for the plugin.

Can some let me know how to set the pod retention value with values never
, always etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing new keyword that is required to create an object. The line

```
    kubernetes.setPodRetention(org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.pod.retention.PodRetention.Never())
```

Should be

```
    kubernetes.setPodRetention(new org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.pod.retention.PodRetention.Never())
```

To configure global pod retention policy go to https://jenkins_url/configure (or https://jenkins_url/configureClouds in latest lts version of jenkins) and update "Pod Retention" configuration grouped under Kubernetes Cloud

Answer (score 0):

Should be
`kubernetes.setPodRetention(new org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.pod.retention.Never())`